# Organize numbers from highest to lowest

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm getting doubles from every file in a folder using

```
if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("baltop")){
        if(!(sender instanceof Player)){
            CommandUtils.invalidCommandSender(sender);
            return true;
        }
        File[] files = new File(ServerCore.getPlugin().getDataFolder(), File.separator + "PlayerData").listFiles();
        for(File file : files){
            FileConfiguration playerData = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
            double bal = playerData.getDouble("Money");
            ChatUtils.sendRawMessage(sender, Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(UUID.fromString(file.getName().replace(".yml", ""))).getName() + ": " + bal);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It says all the prices in order of the files, but i would like to order them from highest to lowest balance, and what happens if two players have the same amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first read all content, and store them in a TreeSet, like this:

```
if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("baltop")){
    if(!(sender instanceof Player)){
        CommandUtils.invalidCommandSender(sender);
        return true;
    }
    TreeSet<Balance> set = new TreeSet<>();
    set = set.descendingSet();
    File[] files = new File(ServerCore.getPlugin().getDataFolder(), File.separator + "PlayerData").listFiles();
    for (File file : files){
        FileConfiguration playerData = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
        double bal = playerData.getDouble("Money");
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(file.getName().replace(".yml", ""));
        set.add(new Balance( Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(uuid).getName(), uuid, bal));
    }

    for (Balance b : set) {
        ChatUtils.sendRawMessage(sender, b.name + ": " + b.balance);
    }
    return true;
}

private static class Balance implements Comparable<Balance> {
    public String name;
    public UUID uuid;
    public double balance;
    public Balance(String n, UUID u, double b) {
        name = n;
        uuid = u;
        balance = b;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Balance b) {
        double d = balance - b.balance;
        if (d<-0.001||d>0.001)
            return (int) Math.signum(d);

        int e = -name.compareToIgnoreCase(b.name);
        if (e != 0)
            return e;
        return -uuid.compareTo(b.uuid);
    }
}
```

This implementation will show balances in descending order of balance, and, if two players have same balance, in the ascending order of their name, regardless of the case. The UUID comparsion is only a last resort of name collision as I don't really know if bukkit allows multiple player with names that only differ in case.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this it helps me so much! Only problem is in the Balance class "return d" gives an eclipse error of "cannot convert from double to int"

Comment: Also in the top class in "TreeSet<Balance> set = new TreeSet<>().descendingSet();" the "new TreeSet<>().descendingSet();" gives an error of "cannot convert from NavigableSet<Object> to TreeSet<Balance>"

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly just wondering would you know how to make it so i can make it "/baltop" to display the top 10 then "/baltop 2" 11-20

Comment: copy all code above, add a counter and only actually send data if counter is in desired range

Comment: Im using your exact code and its been working but all of the sudden im getting an error at "int e = -name.compareToIgnoreCase(b.name);"

Comment: @Kingbluesapphire what error? are you getting a NullPointerException? if so, thta's not something i cohld solve easily. The only cause I could think of is a corrupted balance storage file. there may be a suppressed IOException during the file read, too. Both of these may eventually leads to a null value in the <code>name</code> field, if your FileConfiguration should behave like that, then in turn you got an NPE.

Comment: I changed from saving it as double to bigDecimal but i didnt update that part so it was trying to format it as a double and that must have caused it, i updated it to read it as a bigDecimal, Thanks for your response though!

Comment: Sorry but it seems something isn't working i tried copy the code exactly and switch it to support BigDecimal but it seems to not show them in order from highest or lowest they just come out all random... http://hastebin.com/iyutabamom.java